# Mustache.to_html() returning an empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mustache

This question was asked before but didn't get an answer. I have a php file which sends a json object to a javascript file which is supposed to render it with a template and display it on a div. The problem is, the function Mustache.to_html() returns empty. can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. here's my code.

{

```
    $(":button").click(function(){
    var cat = $(this).attr("name");

    $.get("trier.php",{input: cat}, function(data){
            alert(data);
            var template = $('#templabel').html();
            console.log(template);
            var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
            console.log(html);
            $('#feedback2').html(data);

    }); 
});
```

}

The javascript sends the data to this php file which sends back a json object

{

```
if(isset($_GET['input'])){
    $catt = $_GET['input'];

        $info = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE (Category = '$catt')";
        $information = mysqli_query($conn,$info);
        $arraay = array();

        while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($information)){
            $arraay[] = $r;
        }
        $jason = json_encode($arraay);
        $jason = '{"arraay":'.$jason."}";

        echo $jason;
    }
```

}

The javascript file will then send the json object rendered with the mustache template to the html file, to the tag with the id = "feedback2". But the display is raw json, not templated. and the second console.log after I apply the Mustache.to_html function returns an empty string. What am I doing wrong?

The output of the console.log for the template is

```
{{#arraay}}
        <div>
            <h2> {{Title}}</h2>
            <p>{{Course}}</p>
            <p>{{Category}}</p>
        </div>
    {{/arraay}}
```

and the alert for the data is
{"arraay":[{"Title":"Algorithms","Course":"CSI241","Category":"science"},{"Title":"Fluid dynamics","Course":"PHY345","Category":"science"}]}

Comment: Can we see what `console.log` printed for `data` and `template`?

Comment: Just edit both of them in into your question, don't try to submit them in comments...

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```js
var data = {"arraay":[{"Title":"Algorithms","Course":"CSI241","Category":"science"},{"Title":"Fluid dynamics","Course":"PHY345","Category":"science"}]};
var template = document.getElementById('template').innerHTML;
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
document.getElementById('render').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.2.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
<template id="template">
  {{#arraay}}
        <div>
            <h2> {{Title}}</h2>
            <p>{{Course}}</p>
            <p>{{Category}}</p>
        </div>
  {{/arraay}}
</template>

<div id="render">
</div>
```

Comment: does the mustache tag come before or after the function on top?

Comment: This is just a demonstration of the fact that, if `template` and `data` display on console as you stated, there should be no reason for the render to be empty; one of your presuppositions is likely to be wrong. (In this specific case, the code will be executed when the HTML is already all in; but that is not relevant here.)